# validar con ajax que el contenido de un campo text conste en una base de datos

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, input

Otra vez con mis problemas con ajax.. tengo un formulario donde en un textbox se ingresa un valor el cual debe constar en una tabla. Estoy tratando que esta verificacion se realice al momento en que el usuario termina de llenar este campo y lo abandona par continuar al siguiente elemento. Con este objeto he creado una funcion que se llama validar y quiero realizar esta validacion con ajax. No tuve problemas con identificar el evento ni con la programación del php que se encarga de validar la existencia, pero lo que no puedo controlar es como devuelve el valor de verdad a la pagina del formulario principal para que continue la ejecucion mejor les paso el codigo de las funciones y si alguien me puede explicar como es que ajax recibe las respuestas le agradeceria. Soy nuevo en ajax por lo que aun no le entiendo a su lógica, ademas de que he realizado algunas aproximaciones al problema que funcionan en mi servidor local pero al subirlo a produccion no funcionan para nada. Esta ultima solucion que intento si me ha superado porque no me funciona para nada pero al revisar debería funcionar. El codigo es el siguiente:
para el formulario

```
      <input name="cedula" type="text" class="css-input" id="cedula" onblur="verificarCedula($('#cedula').val())"/>
<span id="resultado" class="spanFont">   </span>
```

para la funcion verificarCedula

```
function verificarCedula(cedula){
 var parametros = {cedula:cedula};
 $.ajax({url:"validar.php",data:parametros,type:"post",
beforeSend:function(){$("#resultado").html("Validando datos...");},
success:function(respuesta){
    if(respuesta =="ok"){
      $("#resultado").html(" "); $('#periodo').prop('disabled',false);
      $('#botonconsulta').prop('disabled',false);getOpciones();}
    else{
     $("#resultado").html("No existe el registro de docente. Verifique los datos...");
     $("#cedula").focus();}
    } })
```

}//funcion verificar cedula

en la funcion aparte de la validacion se activan ciertos inputs dependiendo de la existencia o no del registro

y para el php aparte de la conexion y desconexion a la base de datos tengo esta validacion que devuelve con echo el resultado y esta es la parte que no se como manejar

```
    if(!empty($_POST["cedula"])){
$respuesta="";  
$cedula =$_POST["cedula"];
$sql = "SELECT a.IDENTIFICACION
  FROM afinidad a
 WHERE a.IDENTIFICACION ='$cedula'";
 echo $sql;
// Perform query
$result = $mysqli -> query($sql); 
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        $respuesta = "ok";
    }else{
        $respuesta = "error";
    }

// Free result set
 $result -> free_result();
 echo $respuesta;
}
```

No se cual es el error o si estoy interpretando bien como recibe los datos el ajax, o no se si aparte de la libreria de javascript para jquery deberia incluir alguna cabecera o algo mas estoy más perdido que Santa Claus en mayo y los tutoriales que he buscado no me dan una guia para saber como recibo las respuestas por favor alquien podria orientarme?? muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

te pongo este pequeño ejemplo según comprendo tu problema.
Aquí agrego el **HTML** que según entiendo existe dada la función que tienes, recuerda que **JQuery** se basa en selectores para poder encontrar los elementos del DOM y para ello se utilizan las **ids** y **clases**.

```html
<input name="cedula" type="text" class="css-input" id="cedula" onblur="verificarCedula($('#cedula').val())"/>
<span id="resultado" class="spanFont">  </span>
<input id="periodo" name="periodo" type="text" class="css-input" id="cedula" disabled/>
<button id="botonconsulta" disabled>enviar</button>
```

En esta parte esta la función, la indento un poco para facilitar su lectura y así poder apreciar con claridad los parámetros necesarios para el envío por Ajax.

**NOTA:** Observa que agregue un input para verificar el funcionamiento, el **input** y el **button** aparecen **desabilitados** en primera instancia, con la función modificamos el atributo a **habilitado**.

```js
function verificarCedula(cedula){
    var parametros = {cedula:cedula};
    $.ajax({
        url:"validarCedula.php",
        data:parametros,
        type:"post",
        beforeSend:function(){
            $("#resultado").html("Validando datos...");
        },
        success:function(respuesta){
            console.log(respuesta)
        if(respuesta ==="ok"){
            $("#resultado").html(respuesta); 
            $('#periodo').prop('disabled',false);
            $('#botonconsulta').prop('disabled',false);
        }
        else{
            $("#resultado").html("No existe el registro de docente. Verifique los datos...");
            $("#cedula").focus();}
        } 
    });
}
```

En la parte del procesamiento por PHP, quedaría así. Te recomiendo utilizar **"isset"** para la comprobación de la llegada del dato, esta parte adecuala respecto tu consulta, ya que yo hice un arreglo para poder probar.

```
if(isset($_POST["cedula"])){
$respuesta="";  
$cedula =$_POST["cedula"];
$result = ['juan','perez','administrador'];

    if($result > 0){
        $respuesta = "ok";
        
    }else{
        $respuesta = "error";
    }
 echo $respuesta;
```

}

Comment: muchas gracias, Antonio, por su respuesta! de lo que entiendo para que se ejecuten las funciones en ajax deberia darles a los elementos del formulario esta clase "css-input" pero me surge otra duda, estoy usando unas clases css por motivos esteticos por decirlo asi, debería dejarlo sin esos efectos css para que funcione? gracias por ordenar el codigo y una pregunta más, no necesito agregar nada en la cabecera aparte de la libreria jquery?? muchas gracias otra vez

Comment: Creo te estas confundiendo, los selectores en este caso las clases que mencionas o ids los utilizas para acceder a elementos del DOM con Jquery, esta es una librería desarrollada con javascript, para usar esta librería necesitas agregarla en la cabecera de tu HTML, ya sea por CDN (enlace oficial de Internet) o descargarla y ponerla en tu servidor. Ajax es una tecnología de desarrollo  y necesita ciertos parámetros para su funcionamiento, no es necesario que modifiques tus clases, puedes utilizarlas para otorgar estilos css y al mismo tiempo acceder al elemento y modificarlos con Jquery.

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta puntuala con la flechita hacia arriba.

Comment: Gracias por la explicacion! luego de tu respuesta me puse a leer un poco más, ya tengo clara la idea y la solución funciono, estoy intentando dar flecha arriba pero me dice algo de mi reputación y no me deja registrarla pero en cuanto pueda no dudes que lo voy a hacer estoy intentando desde la primera respuesta